# Dynamically adding parameters to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a plugin called jQuery image map emulator which takes parameters like so:

```
$('#example').imagemap([
{
    top_x: 0,
    top_y: 0,
    bottom_x: 75,
    bottom_y:65,
    callback: alertCallback}
])
```

with multiple arrays possible:

```
$('#example').imagemap([
// One image map
{top_x: 0,top_y: 0,bottom_x: 75,bottom_y:65,callback: alertCallback},

// Another image map
{top_x: 150,top_y: 105,bottom_x: 265,bottom_y:170,callback: alertCallback}
]);
```

How would I go about dynamically adding more of of the parameters as necessary? Ideally I'd have one image map "set" and be able to add more as needed with new coordinates.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options passed into JQuery are just plain javascript objects, so you can define properties on them using the method you've specified above, or just by treating them like a key-value dictionary.

The following is equivalent to your first example:

```
var options = new Array();
options[0] = new Object();
options[0]["top_x"] = 0;
options[0]["top_y"] = 0;
options[0]["bottom_x"] = 75;
options[0]["bottom_y"] = 65;
options[0]["callback"] = alertCallback;

$('#example').imagemap(options);
```

If you want to add new parameters, consider keeping the options variable at a page-level scope, and recalling imagemap with the new parameters whenever they change.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Slight modification was needed: object[0] had to be defined as a new object. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - sorry about that. I've added it in case anyone happens upon this question again.